# How to get Semiotic plot to display in browser

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, graphics, visualization, semiotic

I am brand new to Semiotic (https://semiotic.nteract.io/), and I have what is likely an embarrassingly easy question.  I am trying to make a line chart. How do I get the following Semiotic code - taken directly from https://semiotic.nteract.io/guides/line-chart - to display in my browser?

I have a Mac. What I have tried is to first install `yarn` and then do `yarn add -E semiotic` as the first link says. Next, I copied the below code directly into a text file, which I saved as a `.js` file. I then tried to load it in my web browser, but it just displays the code. What do I need to do differently?

Code:

```
import XYFrame from "semiotic/lib/XYFrame"
const theme = ["#ac58e5","#E0488B","#9fd0cb","#e0d33a","#7566ff","#533f82","#7a255d","#365350","#a19a11","#3f4482"]
const frameProps = {   lines: [{ title: "Ex Machina", coordinates: [{ week: 1, grossWeekly: 327616, theaterCount: 4, theaterAvg: 81904, date: "2015-04-10", rank: 18 },
        { week: 2, grossWeekly: 1150814, theaterCount: 39, theaterAvg: 29508, date: "2015-04-17", rank: 15 },
        { week: 3, grossWeekly: 7156570, theaterCount: 1255, theaterAvg: 5702, date: "2015-04-24", rank: 6 },
        { week: 4, grossWeekly: 3615000, theaterCount: 1279, theaterAvg: 2826, date: "2015-05-01", rank: 6 },
        { week: 5, grossWeekly: 5212462, theaterCount: 2004, theaterAvg: 2601, date: "2015-05-08", rank: 6 },
        { week: 6, grossWeekly: 3108609, theaterCount: 1718, theaterAvg: 1809, date: "2015-05-15", rank: 9 },
        { week: 7, grossWeekly: 2248258, theaterCount: 896, theaterAvg: 2509, date: "2015-05-22", rank: 12 },
        { week: 8, grossWeekly: 1122034, theaterCount: 506, theaterAvg: 2217, date: "2015-05-29", rank: 13 },
        { week: 9, grossWeekly: 551552, theaterCount: 302, theaterAvg: 1826, date: "2015-06-05", rank: 19 },
        { week: 10, grossWeekly: 316877, theaterCount: 194, theaterAvg: 1633, date: "2015-06-12", rank: 20 },
        { week: 11, grossWeekly: 201345, theaterCount: 124, theaterAvg: 1624, date: "2015-06-19", rank: 29 },
        { week: 12, grossWeekly: 153162, theaterCount: 81, theaterAvg: 1891, date: "2015-06-26", rank: 34 },
        { week: 13, grossWeekly: 102114, theaterCount: 61, theaterAvg: 1674, date: "2015-07-03", rank: 36 },
        { week: 14, grossWeekly: 64350, theaterCount: 39, theaterAvg: 1650, date: "2015-07-10", rank: 42 },
        { week: 15, grossWeekly: 45344, theaterCount: 31, theaterAvg: 1463, date: "2015-07-17", rank: 47 }] },
    { title: "Far from the Madding Crowd", coordinates: [{ week: 1, grossWeekly: 240160, theaterCount: 10, theaterAvg: 24016, date: "2015-05-01", rank: 24 },
        { week: 2, grossWeekly: 1090487, theaterCount: 99, theaterAvg: 11015, date: "2015-05-08", rank: 15 },
        { week: 3, grossWeekly: 1831958, theaterCount: 289, theaterAvg: 6339, date: "2015-05-15", rank: 10 },
        { week: 4, grossWeekly: 3779833, theaterCount: 865, theaterAvg: 4370, date: "2015-05-22", rank: 7 },
        { week: 5, grossWeekly: 2246233, theaterCount: 902, theaterAvg: 2490, date: "2015-05-29", rank: 9 },
        { week: 6, grossWeekly: 1129007, theaterCount: 610, theaterAvg: 1851, date: "2015-06-05", rank: 14 },
        { week: 7, grossWeekly: 701207, theaterCount: 366, theaterAvg: 1916, date: "2015-06-12", rank: 17 },
        { week: 8, grossWeekly: 430870, theaterCount: 256, theaterAvg: 1683, date: "2015-06-19", rank: 20 },
        { week: 9, grossWeekly: 270977, theaterCount: 122, theaterAvg: 2221, date: "2015-06-26", rank: 24 },
        { week: 10, grossWeekly: 195483, theaterCount: 105, theaterAvg: 1862, date: "2015-07-03", rank: 28 },
        { week: 11, grossWeekly: 138071, theaterCount: 98, theaterAvg: 1409, date: "2015-07-10", rank: 30 },
        { week: 12, grossWeekly: 86393, theaterCount: 74, theaterAvg: 1167, date: "2015-07-17", rank: 39 },
        { week: 13, grossWeekly: 52821, theaterCount: 47, theaterAvg: 1124, date: "2015-07-24", rank: 42 },
        { week: 14, grossWeekly: 25708, theaterCount: 27, theaterAvg: 952, date: "2015-07-31", rank: 58 },
        { week: 15, grossWeekly: 17292, theaterCount: 18, theaterAvg: 961, date: "2015-08-07", rank: 60 }] }],
  size: [700,400],
  margin: { left: 80, bottom: 90, right: 10, top: 40 },
  xAccessor: "week",
  yAccessor: "theaterCount",
  yExtent: [0],
  lineStyle: (d, i) => ({
    stroke: theme[i],
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: "none"
  }),
  title: (
    <text textAnchor="middle">
      Theaters showing <tspan fill={"#ac58e5"}>Ex Machina</tspan> vs{" "}
      <tspan fill={"#E0488B"}>Far from the Madding Crowd</tspan>
    </text>
  ),
  axes: [{ orient: "left", label: "Number of Theaters", tickFormat: function(e){return e/1e3+"k"} },
    { orient: "bottom", label: { name: "Weeks from Opening Day", locationDistance: 55 } }]
}

export default () => {
  return <XYFrame {...frameProps} />
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: If you want to just see the end result, checkout [this github repo](https://github.com/Symt/my-semiotic-example-app). The project itself was made with the help of [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) to speed things along*

When getting this to render myself, I changed a few things to get it working. The changes I made were to just make it easier for me to setup, and are not all necessary.

1. Put it in a file called `XYFrameWrapper.jsx`
2. Changed the end of the file to:

```
const XYFrameWrapper = () => {
  return <XYFrame {...frameProps} />
}
export default XYFrameWrapper;
```

*Note: These 2 changes just make it easier to put this elsewhere*

3. Added `import React from 'react'` to the start of the file (since it does use react)

*Note: if you are adding this in your website, make sure to do the following steps in your `App.jsx` or equivalent.*

Since you are using react, in your index.js (or in whatever file is the entry point for webpack), make sure to:

1. Import the component: `import XYFrameWrapper from './XYFrameWrapper'`
2. Render the component: `ReactDOM.render(<XYFrameWrapper />, document.getElementById('root'));` OR add it to the `return` statement in your `App.jsx` (or equivalent).

Once all of this is complete, you can start the server and see the output as expected.

About your issue: I think you issue was just opening the JS file in your browser, which will just display the code. If you have any other issues/questions, feel free to comment and I'll make sure to respond ASAP

End Result:
[image: end result image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful.