# semiotic - strokeWidth controls both stroke width and number of fill lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, plot, semiotic

Say that I have this Semiotic code (see [How to get Semiotic plot to display in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571572/how-to-get-semiotic-plot-to-display-in-browser)):

```
import React from "react"

import OrdinalFrame from "semiotic/lib/OrdinalFrame"
const frameProps = { 
/* --- Data --- */
  data: [5,8,2,6,4 ],

/* --- Size --- */
  size: [600,600],
  margin: { left: 100, bottom: 90, right: 10, top: 40 },

/* --- Layout --- */
  type: "bar",
  oPadding: 10,

/* --- Customize --- */
  style: function(e,t){return{fill:t<5?"url(#gradient)":"url(#triangle)",
        fillOpacity:4.5,
        strokeWidth:1,
        stroke: "black",
        strokeOpacity:0.5}},
  additionalDefs: [
    <pattern
      key="triangle"
      id="triangle"
      width="10"
      height="10"
      patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
    >
      <rect fill={"#9fd0cb"} width="10" height="10" />
      <circle fill={"#7566ff"} r="5" cx="3" cy="3" />
    </pattern>,
    <linearGradient key="gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1" id="gradient">
      <stop stopColor={"#dc58e5"} offset="0%" />
      <stop stopColor={"#1111ff"} offset="100%" />
    </linearGradient>
  ],
  renderMode: ("sketchy"),

    title: (
    <text textAnchor="middle">
      Theaters showing <tspan fill={"#ac58e5"}>Ex Machina</tspan> vs{" "}
      <tspan fill={"#E0488B"}>Far from the Madding Crowd</tspan>
    </text>  ),

}

const XYFrameWrapper = () => {
  return <OrdinalFrame {...frameProps} />
}

export default XYFrameWrapper;
```

I have noticed that the `strokeWidth` option alters both the stroke width (the outline of the bars) as well as the number of fill lines. For example, if `strokeWidth` is set to `1`, it gives many lines, but if it set to `10`, it gives very few lines. How can I get it to control only the stroke width? Relatedly, I can't figure out how to get very few lines with only the `fillOpacity` option. I can do this using the `strokeWidth` option, but then of course it makes the stroke width line way too big. How can I achieve very few lines, but have a small stroke width line?

Comment: It's very difficult to gather from your code to which elements the value of `style` is applied. Can you maybe create a JSFiddle or something similar?

Comment: I am brand new to JS. What is JSFiddle and how would I create one?

Comment: It's an online Javascript playground. Just create an account, start a new project, make sure it works with some dummy data and post the link here